# Highcharts datetime starting on wrong day

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I have a php outputting a chart as Javascript, it all displays properly, however, the datetime function on the x-axis isin't starting on the correct date.

I have set the graph like this:

```
xAxis: {
    title:{
        text: 'Day',
        style: {
           color: '#666666',
           fontSize: '12px',
           fontWeight: 'normal'
        }
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%e.%b'   
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
},
```

Then at the series data level:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Office', 
    zIndex: '1',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 17.67, 17.66, 74.8, 62.45, 71.21, 67.75, 22.28, 16.61, 16.26, 71.79, 72.85, 56.52, 48.68, 47.01, 0, 0, 33.8, 62.72, 40.28, 9.99, 26.06, 8.85, 9.46, ],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 7, 14),  
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 //one day
}]
```

So this is clearly set to daily, and to start on the 14th of July 2012. However, when the graph displays, it starts on todays date.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: JS Months start at 0 - so 7th month is August

Comment: Also, you are setting a UTC date so it will be 2012-08-14 00:00:00 UTC. If the local timezone is say -6 hrs, the local time will be 2012-08-13 18:00:00.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 6, 14),
```

for July - JS months start at 0

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect, completely forgot that JS starts at 0, stupid me!